# Is there an easy way to calculate carrier output of a planetary gear set which has two inputs?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms

Online I found many guides and videos on how to calculate outputs of a planetary gearset but all of them have only one input. But how can I calculate output speed of carrier if ring and sun gear are moving at different speeds?

Comment: I believe that it is necessary to provide a correlation between the movement of the ring gear and the sun gear in order to find the answer you seek. Is the ring gear connected to the sun gear by gearing external to the planetary assembly?

Comment: I'm just speaking about a single planetary gearset with two inputs one of which is connected to ring and the other tp sun gear.