# In a planetary gearset is it possible to move both carrier and ring gear at the input speed while holding sun gear stationary?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A friend and I were in a discussion and can't seem to find the answer to the question above. I said it was possible and he said it isn't and now we are both confused so could anyone help here?

Also would it be possible to spin carrier and sun gear while holding ring gear stationary?

Comment: Now you should be able to answer this question yourselves : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29397/10902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you hold the sun gear the carrier will turn at slower speed than the ring gear.

You could have a setting where the ring gear is turning at the same speed as the input speed but then the carrier gear will turn slower or else it will break, because of the fact that is being spinned by the ring gear around the sun gear.

And as to the second part of you question, again if you hold the ring gear the sun gear and carrier will spin at different speeds.
hear is a youtube clip, [planetary gear](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=planetry%20gear%20animation&docid=608052271535164301&mid=7CADA6E2BE3B0EB5CBDB7CADA6E2BE3B0EB5CBDB&view=detail&FORM=VIREHT)